# How to use Jest to test React rendered async data?

Tags: ajax, reactjs, jasmine, jestjs

I am using React for render and Jest/Jasmine for test. I have test written using old Jest/Jasmine `waitsFor` and `runs` but these are gone now in Jasmine 2 and I am not sure how to replace with new `done` asyncs.

In my code React renders a small page about a user. That page has an AJAX call to fetch user posts. I want to test that user posts have come back nice, and `waitsFor` was very, very good at this: wait until user has some post, then continue.

I looked online at lots of people talking about using AJAX calls inside Jest test which is not what I want. My Jest test has no idea about AJAX call being made, so I need a way to wait until results come back.

Here is my current code with `waitsFor` and `runs`:

```
it('loads user post', () => {
    var page = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
        <UserPage params={{user: 'fizzbuzz', 'pass': 'xxx'}} />
    );

    waitsFor(() => {
        return page.state.posts.length > 0;
    }, "post loaded", 10000);

    runs(() => {
        var posts = TestUtils.scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithClass(page, 'post');
        expect(posts.length).toEqual(10);
    });
});
```

How can I delete the `waitsFor` and `runs` and replace with Jasmine 2.0 code that works? All Jest test knows is that `page.state.posts.length` must be greater than 0 before `expect`ing anything.

Answer (score 2):

You should refactor this test into two unit tests that will provide a more rigorous testing of your code. It would make the tests more independent of one another and help identify errors in a more refined scope. These won't be exact as I do not know what your code is like, but here's something along the lines I would expect to see: -

```
it('generates the expected properties for a page', function () {
    var page = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
        <UserPage params={{user: 'fizzbuzz', 'pass': 'xxx'}} />
    );

    expect(page.someProperty).toBeDefined();
    expect(page.user).toEqual('fizzbuzz');
});

it('generates the correct number of posts from a given page object', function () {
    var fakePage = {
        // put your fake mock data here that TestUtils expects
    };

    var posts = TestUtils.scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithClass(fakePage, 'post');

    expect(posts.length).toEqual(10);
});
```

I am not too sure what is happening in your `renderIntoDocument` function so the top test may be a little broken... It looks like there is either too much going on inside the function, or you need to test the calls that function is making instead. If you elaborate on what it does I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Sorry for my slow return! Thankyou! I have added one upvote because I think you are in right direction. renderIntoDocument is not my own code but it is code from React. It renders my React components as if they were being made for real. Render in React causes Ajax to happen and I am trying to ensure the Ajax has completed okay. This was possible in old Jasmine because Ajax could complete inside rendered React component and I check its value in test. But not possible in Jasmine 2 so far.

Comment: @FizzBuzz no worries - thanks for getting back to me! I see, obviously a little in the dark with React at the moment. If it is a native React function though, I would advise against testing this logic because it should already be tested by the developers that are writing that function (i.e. React authors) - stick to testing your own logic beyond (before and after) this function, rather than directly testing their functionality. That's what I would recommend anyways. Apologies if I have misunderstood though - like I said, not got onto React yet.