# How to spy on function calling other function in Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, testing, asynchronous, jasmine

I have the problem:

```
var async = require('async');

function a() {
  async.series([b,c], function(err) {
    console.log('Done');
  });
};
function b(next) {
  next();
};
function c(next) {
  next();
};

var methods = {
  a: a,
  b: b,
  c: c
};
```

And I am trying to write a test like so:

```
spyOn(methods.a);
methods.a();
expect(methods.b).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(methods.c).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

However both b and c do not register as having been called. Any ideas how to properly test this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

If you use spy on function or method then Jasmine will be look at this function for check call it. And called function under Jasmine Spy is not execute its code by default.

```
spyOn(methods, "a");
methods.a();
expect(methods.a).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

In your case, you need check async code execution. We can do it with `done` function:

```
it("should support async execution", function(done) {
    var MAX_ASYNC_DELAY = 2000;
    spyOn(methods, "b");
    spyOn(methods, "с");
    methods.a();
    setTimeout(function(){
        expect(methods.b).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(methods.c).toHaveBeenCalled();
        done();
    }, MAX_ASYNC_DELAY );
});
```

It will work if in `methods.a()` you will use next:

```
function a() {
     async.series([methods.b, methods.c], function(err) {
          console.log('Done');
     });
}
```

If such adjustment is not possible, you should rewrite the test case in the following:

```
it("should support async execution", function(done) {
    var MAX_ASYNC_DELAY = 2000;
    spyOn(window, "b");
    spyOn(window, "с");
    methods.a();
    setTimeout(function(){
        expect(b).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(c).toHaveBeenCalled();
        done();
    }, MAX_ASYNC_DELAY );
});
```

[Owen Ayres](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37318781/6220422) advises not to use `setTimeout` in the test case. But this is impossible in your case if you are using Jasmine. Because `jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL` is timeout waiting for call `done` function. 
Example, your async timeout is eqaul nearly 10000 ms and you set `MAX_ASYNC_DELAY` to 11000 ms. The test case will be marked as failed, because `jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL` equal 5000 ms by default. That need use override this param:

```
var originalTimeout;
beforeEach(function() {
    originalTimeout = jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL;
    jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 12000; // ms to wait for done()
});
it("should support async execution", function(done) {
    var MAX_ASYNC_DELAY = 11000;
    // test case from above
});
afterEach(function() {
    jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = originalTimeout;
});
```

if you use Jasmine version 2.2 and above you can write:

```
it("should support async execution", function(done) {
    var MAX_ASYNC_DELAY = 11000;
    // test case from above
}, 12000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid `setTimeout` in a unit test at all costs. Here is how you should test it in a readable, 'Triple A Testing' format. Using Jasmine's async `done` will ensure it waits for a certain length of time before failing if the function call is never made. If you want to customise this for this test case, you could do something like defined in my beforeEach below (but inside the test itself).

```
beforeEach(function() {
    // these are not required, including to show you can have if desired
    originalTimeout = jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL;
    jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 10000; // ms to wait for done()
});

it('calls methods b and c when a is called', function (done) {
    var a = spyOn(methods.a);
    var b = spyOn(methods.b);

    methods.a();

    expect(a).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(b).toHaveBeenCalled();
    done();
});

afterEach(function() {
    // could be inline of above test if not needed for multiple cases.
    jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = originalTimeout;
});
```

**Do not use timeouts** in the test. This is not a clean way of testing and should be avoided unless *absolutely* essential.

Comment: "Do not use timeouts" --- How else can you delay thing? `waitsFor` is gone :( :( :(  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37310701/how-to-use-jest-to-test-react-rendered-async-data

Comment: @FizzBuzz I've answered your question but you might want to elaborate on your code a little